# Different versions of PHP on OS X 10.9

Tags: php, symfony, osx-mavericks

I am trying to get the Symphony framework installed on my laptop (running OS X 10.9 Mavericks), so far I can't even get it started because of error messages

The first thing not being an error but it seems that I have multiple versions of PHP running and I would like to remove everything except the latest version (5.5.12). Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this?

I compiled and built the newest version of PHP from source and installed it (which should replace the original version), however I am seeing 2 different versions when using `phpinfo()` from a webpage and `php -v` from the command line:

```
phpinfo(): PHP Version 5.4.24

php -v: PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: May 29 2014 11:21:46)
```

Comment: did you bother reconfiguring apache to point at the .so for the new version? It's probably still loading the .so for the original version.

Comment: I really recommend moving this over to SuperUser or apple.stackexchange. It is a very good question (and something I've found *very* annoying to deal with), but not the best for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

> I compiled and built the newest version of PHP from source and
>   installed it (which should replace the original version), however I am
>   seeing 2 different versions when using `phpinfo()` from a webpage and
>   `php -v` from the command line:

PHP from the command line is 100% different from PHP as loaded via an Apache module. So wiping out the old version won’t solve this issue & might cause other issues. Don’t ever attempt that. Instead just install the version of PHP you want to run and edit your Apache config to load the proper `libphp5.so` PHP 5.5.12 module.

In my Mac OS X 10.9.3 install the default system Apache config is located here:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

And in there is a commented out line—might be uncommented in yours—that reads:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

So you need to just make sure you create a similar line to the `libphp5.so` PHP 5.5.12 module like so:

```
LoadModule php5_module /path/to/the/new/version/of/php/libphp5.so
```

Making sure to change that `/path/to/the/new/version/of/php/` to match your actual `libphp5.so` PHP 5.5.12 module.

Then restart the Apache web service & all should be good.

Remember this: When it comes to Unix/Linux tools & configurations, you never have to forcefully uninstall components to solve issues like this. It’s all about getting the configuration straight.

All that said, you might make your live easier by running [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/) instead of compiling from source like this. MAMP is a self-contained LAMP stack for MAMP that has the latest versions of PHP installed.  And since it runs as an application, none of the issues you are facing compiling from source will ever happen when you use MAMP.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help. I realized that I had installed so many things with MacPorts (programming my Arduino among other things) that I just decided to wipe my drive and reinstall OS X 10.9

Then I just followed this tutorial and finally got everything working properly

http://dab.io/posts/install-symfony-on-os-x-mavericks.html